# Docker image with systemd creates /run/nologin in the filesystem, how can I prevent this?

Tags: docker, systemd

In my dockerfile I try to create an image with systemd properly installed and configured:

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy

RUN apt-get update ; \
    apt-get install -y systemd systemd-sysv ; \
    apt-get clean ; \
# ...many rm commands here...
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

I am creating an running the container in a following way:

```
docker run --privileged --name my_container -d -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro my_image
```

Getting the console to the create container, I see in the filesystem /run/nologin. I can manually delete it, but it **recreated every time when I stop then restart the container**.

Because of limited systemd knowledge, I do not know is this an error or by design, and why it is rcreated.

Is this an error or by design, and what can I do for fix if this is an error, or how to prevent recreated it if this is by design?

Comment: It's usually easiest to think of a container as a wrapper around a single _process_; systemd wants to manage a lot of things that are usually isolated in a container (you shouldn't normally need to run a `--privileged` container).  You don't say why you're using systemd; can you use a lighter-weight process manager like supervisord, or better still, split up your application into multiple single-process containers?

Comment: many thx for your comments. I need to provision test, developer, and training student machines not having systemd is not an option. Many scripts, training material etc rely on that. It will not be a production machine or container. On production either I use a compute resource (which has systemd properly installed and configured) or PAAS container, orchestration and registry services, with similar container concept and architecture what you recommended.

Comment: "Provision machines" definitely sounds more like a VM setup than a Docker setup.  This also sounds like it's not especially a programming-related problem but rather a system-administration problem, and another site like [sf] might be a more appropriate place to ask.  A VM will also look and act in almost all ways like your cloud compute resource, where a container can have a very different environment.

Comment: I did not write "provision machines". On "provision test" I meant testing provision, with more words: testing provision scripts. You are right this question also fits to serverfault, however writing dockerfile also fits here. I also admit, having a systemd docker image not a mainstream, but completly a legit use case.